# Add user to SharePoint 2010 group using powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

We need to add several users to several SharePoint Groups.

Does anyone have an example of how to add a user to a sharepoint group using power shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this PowerShell script:

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'fun/factory' -Web http://someserver -Group 'Name of group'
```

Answer (score 16):

To add multiple users to multiple groups, you could use a longer script:

```
Function AddUsers($userArray, $webUrl)
{
    foreach ($user in $userArray)
    {
        $username = $user[0];
        foreach ($group in $user[1])
        {
            Set-SPUser -Identity $username -Web $webUrl -Group $group
        }
    }
}



$userArray = @(
    @("domain\user1", @("Site Visitors", "Designers")),
    @("domain\user2", @("Site Visitors", "Designers")),
    @("domain\user3", @("Site Owners"))
    )

#Call function without brackets
AddUsers $userArray "http://my-sharepoint-site/"
```